# Cocartesian fibration classifying $\mathrm{Fun}(F,G)$

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Throughout this question we consider $\infty$-categories.

Fix a cartesian fibration $p : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{C}$ and a cocartesian fibration $q : \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{C}$ which straighten to $F : \mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ and $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ respectively.
We may thereby form a functor $\mathrm{Fun}(F(-),G(-)) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ which then must classify a cocartesian fibration over $\mathcal{C}$.

In Example 4.10 of [Fibrations in $\infty$-category theory](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-72299-3_2), Barwick and Shah propose that this ought to be the cocartesian fibration $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{C}$ determined by the following universal property:

$$
\hom_{/\mathcal{C}}(K,\mathcal{H}) \cong
\hom_{/\mathcal{C}}(K \times_\mathcal{C} \mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})
$$

(That is, the local exponential $\mathcal{G}^\mathcal{F}$. Note that $K \to \mathcal{C}$ is *not* required to be a cocartesian fibration. That this construction actually yields a cocartesian fibration is discussed by Lurie in Higher Topos Theory.)

In Warning 4.11, they note that they do not know of a proof that this is actually the case; only that the induced straightening functor on homotopy categories is correct. They note that a special case was discussed by [Gepner, Haugseng, and Nikolaus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02161), but even this special case relies on some complex naturality arguments.

**Has a proof of this fact appeared in the time since this paper was published?**